# Интреграция React в Ruby API

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, интеграция

Я написала фронт на react и сейчас пытаюсь интегрировать фронт в ruby blog. Использую эту инструкцию - третий вариант https://sloboda-studio.com/blog/how-to-integrate-react-with-ruby-on-rails/

- Перенесла папку с реактом внурть blog >> app >> react
- Запустила blog
- Попыталась запустить react... но что-то пошло не так. Из подсказок в терминале удалила yarn.lock и node-moduls, но это не помогло.

> react-scripts start
>
> There might be a problem with the project dependency tree. It is
> likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix
> locally.
>
> The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a
> dependency:
>
> "babel-loader": "8.0.6"
>
> Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it
> automatically. However, a different version of babel-loader was
> detected higher up in the tree:
>
> /Users/maria/Documents/PROJECTS/FamilyList-Project/FamilyList_v7/blog/node_modules/babel-loader
> (version: 8.2.2)
>
> Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause
> hard-to-debug issues.
>
> If you would prefer to ignore this check, add
> SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project. That will
> permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.
>
> To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact
> order:
>
> 1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
> 2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
> 3. Remove "babel-loader" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
> 4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.
>
> In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem. If this has
> not helped, there are a few other things you can try:
>
> 5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
>    This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.
> 6. Check if /Users/maria/Documents/PROJECTS/FamilyList-Project/FamilyList_v7/blog/node_modules/babel-loader
>    is outside your project directory.
>    For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.
> 7. Try running npm ls babel-loader in your project folder.
>    This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed babel-loader.
>
> If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file
> in your project. That would permanently disable this preflight check
> in case you want to proceed anyway.
>
> P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-)
> We hope you find them helpful!
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! family-list@0.1.0
> start: `react-scripts start` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR!  npm ERR!
> Failed at the family-list@0.1.0 start script. npm ERR! This is
> probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging
> output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> /Users/maria/.npm/_logs/2021-04-09T11_19_45_401Z-debug.log

- И после удаления node-moduls

> sh: react-scripts: command not found npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR!
> syscall spawn npm ERR! file sh npm ERR! errno ENOENT npm ERR!
> family-list@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start` npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
> npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the family-list@0.1.0 start script. npm
> ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
> additional logging output above. npm WARN Local package.json exists,
> but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> /Users/maria/.npm/_logs/2021-04-09T11_19_02_189Z-debug.log
> maria@maria-computer react % npm start

Как мне исправить ошибку при запуске?

Comment: ошибки нужно добавлять текстом а не картинками https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Очень странная и невнятная инструкция. Третий пункт говорит о двух раздельных приложениях и после этого пытается засунуть реактовую часть внутрь рельсового приложения без каких-либо дополнительных инструментов... У вас какой опыт с Ruby on Rails? И почему не стали использовать webpacker или react-on-rails?

Comment: У меня немного опыта с react и вообще никакого с ruby, поэтому решила попробовать ruby blog.
Меньше часа назад мне удалось это сделать заменив в blog babel-loader, webpack и webpack-dev-server. И blog и react запустились. Сейчас пытаюсь вникнуть где создается "proxy for API calls"... если вы знаете где более лучшая инструкция для новичков, пожалуйста, поделитесь.

Comment: Вот например - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-ruby-on-rails-project-with-a-react-frontend

Comment: Спасибо, Василиса! Попробую по этой инструкции 